Output of op-amp in Multisim and CircuitLab
I have two identical circuits of op-amp one in MultiSim and one in CircuitLab. They show different current out of the op-amp and I am not sure why.
Here is the MultiSim circuit.
In case it is not loading, here is a screenshot:

And here is one from CircuitLab:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
To summarize: MultiSim shows no current, while CircuitLab shows 200 mA. Why?

Move the green current probe slightly to the right (onto the red wire). And re-run the simulation. And you will get 200mA. But in the real world, most op-amps can't supply such a high current. Typically 20mA is a high current for most op-amps. Thus, this result is purely theoretical.

Model of TL081 is not "real" ?

@Antonio51 I have no idea. I simply used CircuitLab. You probably can click on link "simulate this circuit" and get more details.

The Multisim diagram shows positive feedback. The Circuit Lab diagram shows negative feedback

Supply voltages not indicated for either circuit.

@RussellH, There is 1 volt DC on the left or do you mean voltage rails? This meant to be ideal OpAmp.


I have two identical circuits of OpAmp one in MultiSim and one in CircuitLab.

No. You have two different circuits.

They show different current out of OpAmp and I am not sure why.
MultiSim shows no current

The load currents are the same in both cases. Why MultiSim is not showing op-amp output current is anybody's guess. You should ask the folks at National Instruments perhaps?

Of course, most op-amps cannot supply more than a couple 10s of mA of output current, so these circuits wouldn't actually work in practice unless you were using a power op-amp designed to supply such high output currents.
For common "signal" op-amps, R1, R2 and R3 should be 100x higher at least, e.g. 1kΩ

Look carefully:


You're also lucky because these two circuit configurations will produce the same load current in R3. That's not usually the case :)

Here is a more "realistic" simulation (except "current power supplies !).
The Current is limited to ~ 20 mA at opamp output.
Made with microcap v12
Circuit 1:

And
Circuit 2:

